# Erro Use of undeclared type , ao tentar usar o identificador de uma tela para transporte de informaçoes, para outra

Tags: ios, swift

Estou estudando swift e no momento estou tentando fazer um aplicativo com mais de uma tela, bem simples.

Mas estou tendo problemas ao trabalhar com essas ligaçoes entre telas, do storyboard.

Identifiquei uma dos componentes de uma das telas como `ToDoItem`, imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando ter o click na linha e transportar o valor para outra tela, mas, não consigo fazer o `cast` para o identificador `ToDoItem`, xcode sempre me retorna um erro:

Segue o código da ToDoList:

```
class ToDoListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var toDoItems: [ToDoItemModel] = [ToDoItemModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        title = "To Do List"
        
        let testItem = ToDoItemModel(name: "Test Item", details: "TestDetails", completionDate: Date())
        self.toDoItems.append(testItem)
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let selectedItem = toDoItems[indexPath.row]
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "TaskDetailsSegue", sender: selectedItem ) // -> passa dados para outra tela
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return toDoItems.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let toDoItem = toDoItems[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoItem")!
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = toDoItem.isComplete ? "Complete" : "Incomplete"
        
        return cell
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "TaskDetailsSegue"{
            
            guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ToDoDetailsViewController else { return }
            
            guard let toDoItem = sender as? ToDoItem else { return } //erro
            
            destinationVC.toDOItem = toDoItem
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

O erro `Use of undeclared type 'ToDoItem'` aparece na linha guard `let toDoItem = sender as? ToDoItem else { return }`

O que devo fazer para que eu consiga pegar esta informaçao e leva-la a outra tela deste storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro indica que ele não conhece o tipo `ToDoItem`.

Você está passando no sender o seguinte:

```
        let selectedItem = toDoItems[indexPath.row]
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "TaskDetailsSegue", sender: selectedItem )
```

Ou seja, o sender é um elemento do array toDoItens, que por sua vez é do tipo:

```
var toDoItems: [ToDoItemModel]
```

logo, cada elemento é um `ToDoItemModel`.

Substitua a linha pelo seguinte:

```
guard let toDoItem = sender as? ToDoItemModel else { return } //erro
```

e isso deve trazer o resultado esperado.

Comment: entendi, muito obrigado